# CSS: Menu won't get vertical

Tags: css, menu

I'm actually learning CSS and I don't get the Menu Bar vertical. Any one can help with the code?
I've tried many variations, but don't get my result.

```
ul.sqlmenu {
        display:block;
        text-align: center;
        float:left;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #2c2c2c;
        margin-top: -860px;
        margin-left: 8px;
        margin-right:10px;
        width: 180px;
        height: 45px;
    }
    ul.sqlmenu li {
        display:inline-table;
        float: left;
    }
    ul.sqlmenu li a {
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    ul.sqlmenu li a:hover{
        background-color:darkslategray;
        width:180px;
    }
```

AND

```
    <ul class="sqlmenu">
        <li><a href="folgt">SELECT</a></li>
    <   li><a href="folgt">ADD</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: If you want the list items stacked vertically, remove `ul.sqlmenu li { display:inline-table; float: left; }`. See [float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with using `display: flex;` with `flex-direction: column;`

```css
ul.sqlmenu {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #2c2c2c;
  margin-left: 8px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  flex-direction: column;
}

ul.sqlmenu li {
  display: inline-table;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
}

ul.sqlmenu li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px;
}

ul.sqlmenu li a:hover {
  background-color: darkslategray;
  width: 180px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="sqlmenu">
  <li><a href="folgt">SELECT</a></li>
  <li><a href="folgt">ADD</a></li>
</ul>
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/851jm70e/)

Comment: Why are list items floated left?